# rsync: entrylevel 1

Tags: rsync, cwrsync

i try to sync a local diretory to a remote system with rsync (cwrsync for win) now i have a problem with the entrylevel and can't find a solution.

```
Sourcedir: /cygdrive/c/temp/dirA
Destdir: /cygdrive/e/temp/destination
```

The entrylevel for sync is 0, its mean the destination is: /cygdrive/e/temp/destination/dirA but it should be /cygdrive/e/temp/destination/{content from sourcedir} But i cant find a Switch to change the entrylevel for rsync.

Any ideas?

Regards
Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to rsync the contents of a directory and not the directory you need to have the `/` at the end of the pathname like:

```
/cygdrive/c/temp/dirA/
```